# Is it possible to know/resolve multiple DNS names to IP "wildcard like"?

Tags: domain-name-system

Is it possible to know/resolve multiple DNS names to IP "wildcard like"? For example:

```
*.telemetry.microsoft.com
```

Maybe it is a two step process, first get the DNS names are matching, then resolve them one by one, that is completely fine. The point is to automate the whole process.

(I would like to automate adding Windows firewall rules, so first I need to resolve them to their respecive IPv4 and IPv6)

Comment: In what context are you trying to do this? Every lookup requires a specific reference. Generally you *can* use DNS name wildcards in things like firewall rules because the firewall will do a *reverse* lookup from the IP address, which is distinct and known from the connection being evaluated. You *can't* use them from tools like nslookup to resolve to an IP address, because a name with a wildcard is not distinct.

Comment: Windows firewall does not allow DNS names, just IP

Comment: A host-level firewall (especially one with that kind of limitation) should primarily be used to limit connections within a *single subnet*: say between app servers and a db server - a very limited set of allowed connections. For handling a broader range of clients like web app users, use a stand-alone, purpose built firewall or router with rules that can be applied more universally. Trying to manage hundreds or thousands of constantly changing individual IP addresses that could be part of a domain range is going to be a nightmare and may well push this firewall beyond its limits.

Comment: For instance, what happens if an IP address is added to or removed from DNS between updates to your firewall? Legitimate clients could be denied access, or revoked clients allowed through, unless your rules are always in sync with DNS. A firewall that is limited to IP address-specific rules just isn't going to deal with that reliably - it will be insecure and error-prone by definition unless you also control the DNS records and can guarantee they are always in sync.

Comment: All true. I do know the limitation of the method I've chosen.

Comment: At any rate, I don't think there's a simple way to do what you're asking.

Comment: Look at any nameserver RPZ feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done, at least not easily. In order to know what servers are registered in a domain, you would need to ask those from the nameserver, which would mean a zone transfer, which is something most sane DNS server will deny. You can guess or harvest host names, but there is no way to explicitly enumerate all hostnames in a domain without having access to the DNS server of that domain.

Comment: Thx, I've realized that permission must be granted some way to do what I want